# Grails Resources modules: programmatic equivalent to r:require?

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, resources

I'm using modules to handle resource dependencies and bundling in a Grails application:

```
'module1' {
    resource url: '/path/to/resource1-1.js';
    resource url: '/path/to/resource1-2.js';
}

'module2' {
    dependsOn 'module1';

    resource url: '/path/to/resource2-1.js';
    resource url: '/path/to/resource2-2.js';
}
```

This will create 2 bundles for the example above, one for each module (note: the exact bundle name may vary according to some configurations):

```
/app/static/bundle-bundle_module1_defer.js
/app/static/bundle-bundle_module2_defer.js
```

Now, I'm implementing a Web Worker which uses `module2`. When constructing a Worker, one needs to specify the URL of the JS files it will use, so if I knew which the generated bundles' names, it would be something like:

```
var worker = new Worker('/app/static/bundle-bundle_module1_defer.js', '/app/static/bundle-bundle_module2_defer.js');
```

**The question is: how to programmatically obtain these 2 URLs corresponding to 'module2' (and its dependencies)?** I'm looking for something like the [r:require](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/ref/Tags/require.html) tag, with the difference that the `require` tag generates complete `<script>` tags

```
<script src="/app/static/bundle-bundle_module1_defer.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/app/static/bundle-bundle_module2_defer.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

and I just need the 2 URLs above.

**UPDATE** Added some examples on the Web Worker part.

Comment: I'm not grokking what you are trying to do here... maybe provide some examples of the "specific URLs" you are wanting to generate and why you can't simply put this in a GSP with a require tag.

Comment: Hope it's more clear now. r:require adds full script tags, but I need their URLs instead.

Comment: Have a look at the source code at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-resources/blob/master, maybe there you could find something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developed an utility class which tries to reuse existing code as much as possible:

```
class ResourceProcessorUtil {
    def static externalURLPattern = /^((https?:?)?\/\/).*/

    static Map getResources(grailsApplication, moduleNameList) {
        def grailsResourceProcessor = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('grailsResourceProcessor')
        def resourceTagLib = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceTagLib')

        def modulesNeeded = grailsResourceProcessor.getAllModuleNamesRequired(moduleNameList)
        def modulesInOrder = grailsResourceProcessor.getModulesInDependencyOrder(modulesNeeded)

        def resources = [:]
        for (moduleName in modulesInOrder) {
            def module = grailsResourceProcessor.getModule(moduleName)
            for (r in module.resources) {
                if (!r.exists() && !isExternalURL(r.actualUrl)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Module [$moduleName] depends on resource [${r.sourceUrl}] but the file cannot be found")
                }

                def info = resourceTagLib.resolveLinkUriToUriAndResource([uri: "${r.actualUrl}"])
                resources.put(info.uri, info.resource)
            }
        }

        return resources
    }

    static Boolean isExternalURL(url){
        return url ==~ externalURLPattern
    }
}
```

Calling it from a Controller (for example)

```
ResourceProcessorUtil.getResources(grailsApplication, ['some-module', 'an-additional-module'])
```

will return a Map `<key,value> = <'uri', ResourceMeta>` with all resources, correctly ordered according to the plugin's dependency resolution.

Note: tested with resources plugin 1.2.1. The `isExternalURL` method is already implemented in the dev version within URLUtils.

Note2: opened a suggestion for this at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-249

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/3.%20Declaring%20resources.html#3.1.3%20The%20defaultBundle%20method), you can change the name of the bundle that will be generated with your resources:

```
'module1' {
    resource url: '/path/to/resource1-1.js'
    resource url: '/path/to/resource1-2.js'
    defaultBundle 'module1'
}

'module2' {
    dependsOn 'module1';
    resource url: '/path/to/resource2-1.js'
    resource url: '/path/to/resource2-2.js'

    defaultBundle 'module2'
}
```

Comment: That would still require me to manually include module2, module1 and all other dependencies that might exist (so I wouldn't be using the resource module dependency mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything in Grails to do this easily but you could try to do it client-side instead? Assuming you can include the script files in your page, then you could extract their `src` attributes and create the worker url from that:

```
<script id="script1" src="/js/script1.js"></script>
```

and

```
var script1Url = document.getElementById("script1").src;
var worker = new Worker(script1Url);
```

Yes, this seems like a hack and if the scripts are huge then it might impact rendering to have the browser load them twice(?).

Comment: Would have the downsides you mention, but I think it would work! Still prefer the utility class though, reuses most code so I guess it's not too awful.